# What is the test statistic in Fisher's exact test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, fishers-exact-test, hypergeometric-distribution

For a 2 by 2 contingency table, some said [Fisher's exact test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_exact_test) uses the count $X_{1,1}$ in the (1,1) cell in the table as the test statistic, and under null hypothesis, $X_{1,1}$ will have a hypergeometric distribution.

Some said its test statistic is 
$$
|X_{1,1} - \mu|
$$
where $\mu$ is the mean of the hypergeometric distribution (mentioned above) under null. It also said that p-values is determined based on the tabel of hypergometric distribution. I was wondering if there is some reason to subtract mean and then to take absolute value? $|X_{1,1} - \mu|$ doesn't have a hypergeometric distribution under null, does it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

(To make our notions a little more precise, let's call the 'test statistic' the distribution of the thing we look up to actually compute the p-value. This means that for a two-tailed t-test, our test statistic would be $|T|$ rather than $T$.)

What a test statistic *does* is induce an ordering on the sample space (or more strictly, a partial ordering), so that you can identify the extreme cases (the ones most consistent with the alternative).

In the case of Fisher's exact test, there's *already* an ordering in a sense - which are the probabilities of the various 2x2 tables themselves. As it happens, they correspond to the ordering on $X_{1,1}$ in the sense that either the largest or smallest values of $X_{1,1}$ are 'extreme' and they are *also* the ones with smallest probability. So rather than look at the values of $X_{1,1}$ in the way you suggest, one can simply work in from the large and small ends, at each step just adding whichever value (the largest or smallest $X_{1,1}$-value not already in there) has the smallest probability associated with it, continuing until you reach your observed table; on its inclusion, the total probability of all those extreme tables is the p-value.

Here's an example:

[image: hypergeometric probability function]

```
> data.frame(x=x,prob=dhyper(x,9,12,10),rank=rank(dhyper(x,9,12,10)))
   x         prob rank
1  0 1.871194e-04    2
2  1 5.613581e-03    4
3  2 5.052223e-02    6
4  3 1.886163e-01    8
5  4 3.300786e-01   10
6  5 2.829245e-01    9
7  6 1.178852e-01    7
8  7 2.245433e-02    5
9  8 1.684074e-03    3
10 9 3.402171e-05    1
```

The first column are $X_{1,1}$ values, the second column are the probabilities and the third column is the induced ordering.

So in the particular case of the Fisher exact test, *the probability of each table (equivalently, of each $X_{1,1}$ value) can be considered the actual test statistic*.

If you compare your suggested test statistic $|X_{1,1}-\mu|$, it induces the *same* ordering in this case (and I believe it does so in general but I have not checked), in that larger values of that statistic are the smaller values of the probability, so it could equally be considered 'the statistic' - but so could many other quantities -- indeed any that preserve this ordering of the $X_{1,1}$s in all cases are equivalent test statistics, because they always produce identical p-values.

Also note that with the more precise notion of 'test statistic' introduced at the start, none of the possible test statistics for this problem actually has a hypergeometric distribution; $X_{1,1}$ does, but it's not actually a suitable test statistic for the two tailed test (if we did a one-sided test where only more association in the main diagonal and not in the second diagonal was regarded as consistent with the alternative, then it would be a test statistic). This is just the same one-tailed/two-tailed issue I began with.

[Edit: some programs do present a test statistic for the Fisher test; I'd presume this would be a -2logL type calculation that would be asymptotically comparable with a chi-square. Some may also present the odds-ratio or its log but that's not quite equivalent.]

Comment: THanks, Glen_b! the distribution of $X_{1,1}$ under null  is the hypergeometric distribution, which is not symmetric around its mean $\mu$. So I was wondering if $|X_{1,1} - \mu|$ is a reasonable test statistic?

Comment: It seems an eminently reasonable test statistic, since it's completely interpretable and readily understood. Indeed none of the possible statistics will have a symmetric distribution. Let's forget the specifics of the Fisher test for a moment - if that statistic is meaningful for you, you can calculate an [exact test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_test) on that basis (using hypergeometric calculations to find the probabilities). If you want to show that they're inducing the same ordering in all cases, that's probably a new question.

Answer (score 6):

$|X_{1,1} - \mu|$ cannot have a hypergeometric distribution in general because $\mu$ does not need to be an integer value and then $|X_{1,1} - \mu|$ would not be an integer. But conditionally on the margins, $X_{1,1}$ will have a hypergeometric distribution.

If you do it properly and fix the margins to known values, you can consider $X_{1,1}$ (or any other cell) to be your statistic. With the analogy of drawing $k$ balls from an urn containing $W$ white balls and $B$ black balls without replacement, $X_{1,1}$ can be interpreted as the number of white balls drawn, where $B$ is the sum of the first row, $W$ is the sum of the second row, $k$ is the sum of the first column.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't really have one. Test statistics are a historical anomaly - the only reason we have a test statistic is to get to a p-value. Fisher's exact test jumps past a test statistic and goes straight to a p-value.

Comment: Thank, but is there really not a test statistic? How do you determine the p value then?

Comment: The result of Fisher's exact test is the p-value.

Comment: @JeremyMiles: Do you mean test statistics are historical anomalies in that prior to low-cost computing, users calculated Z, t and so on and then compared this test statistic to the pre-calculated tables to determine statistical significance, and as a result, many current users of inferential statistics still think in terms of test statistics when they could just as easily provide a p-value? In other words, is this a sort of generational effect?

Comment: @rabidotter - yes, I guess I do. You see people who write "F = 14.352, df = 2, 568, p < 0.05". Pretty much the only reason anyone cares about F is to calculate P, yet they give F to massive precision, and p to very little precision.